# Avoiding File Corruption due to Power Outages

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I'm writing a simple application  in .Net C# that will upload ZIP files to a central server for processing.

However, the environment that this application will be use it is susceptible to frequent power outages.

I'm currently reading the file in using File.ReadAllBytes and uploading by passing the resulting byte array to WebClient.UploadData.

Assuming that a power outage interrupts the call to ReadAllBytes, could file corruption occur and how best to deal with that possibility?

Thanks,

Roberto

Comment: Random thought: get a UPS?

Comment: In the abstract, yes. But its not going to be possible for the end users :)

Comment: Is the file on an NTFS volume? That will be 'safer' but not safe : http://superuser.com/questions/194412/is-ntfs-fail-safe-in-case-of-a-power-outage

Comment: ReadAllBytes() is incapable of corrupting files.  What happens when UploadData() is interrupted depends entirely on the server's FTP or HTTP implementation.  Finding that out ought to not to take long, use Task Manager to kill the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a power outage interrupts the reading, of course the reading will be aborted. I do not understand this part of the question. You should be concerned about *writing*.

Two kinds of writes can go wrong here:

1. Writing the ZIP to disk. If interrupted you get a partial file. You can make this safe by first writing the ZIP to a temp file and then renaming it only once it is complete. You also must insert a `Flush` before renaming. Renaming is atomic and crash-safe on NTFS.
2. Writing to the server over the network. You can make that safe by first submitting the expected file length (or hash). The server must validate that length to make sure transmission completed.

If any kind of error is detected using these methods you need to restart the process.